# Getting querystring at app start (app.component.ts) in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to get query parameters passed in app.component, when the app starts. Activated route doesn't fit, as this is app startup and there hasn't been any routing.
I am using the router event ActtvationEnd:

```
 this.subParams = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
      take(1),
      tap(event =>{
        this.params = convertToParamMap((event as ActivationEnd).snapshot.queryParams);
```

This works, but as I need to evaluate user status and decide where to redirect, I am wondering whether there is a way to get them synchronously. I have to make many choices based on query parameters, and putting all startup code in a tap, inside a pipe, makes things overcomplicated. Any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Does adding a Guard with something like **CanActivate** help with your scenario ? (doc here: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: Not sure if [this long github conversation](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12157) can help

Comment: @Picci really useful, thanks, even if it showed that there are no clean solutions at the moment, ant there haven't been for almost 5 years